# Como pegar o valor de um campo na mesma página

Tags: php

Tenho um campo de formulário em uma página chamada cadastro.php, por exemplo.
Então quero criar uma variável que receba o valor que o usuário digitar neste campo, mas quero que esta variável esteja no mesmo código e não em outra página, mas não sei como pegar esse valor, pois ela não está sendo passada nem via post nem via get. Tem como?

tipo sei que não é assim, mas vou colocar esse exemplo para quem quiser responder.

campo: `<input type="text" name="nome"/>`

aí quero extrair para uma variável que estará no mesma página do código o valor que o usuário digitar...

`$nome = $_GET['nome'];`. Sei que não é assim, mas como faço isso? Ou não tem jeito?

Comment: Você quer que ocorra paginação ou não?

Comment: Com PHP não tem como, se é que entendi o que quer fazer, mas com JavaScript é possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bastaria usar o `action=""` vazio e fazer assim:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['nome'])) {
    $nome = $_GET['nome'];

    echo 'Olá', htmlentities($nome), '!';
}
?>
<form method="get" action="">
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome">
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Dessa maneira a requisição vai pra "mesma" página que você enviar o form.

Mas claro que isso vai fazer **paginar**, mesmo que fosse POST, se o que você quer é atualizar uma variavel sem páginar, não tem como, pois Web é HTTP e HTTP funciona assim:

[image: htt]

Ou seja sempre terá que ter requisição e resposta, no entanto você pode usar Ajax e talvez combinar com sessão, depende muito do que você de fato deseja fazer.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento